# C++ Check whether the user input is float or not

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to check if the user input a valid float or not. Curiously, it seems that this can be done for an `int`, but when I change my code to read a `float` instead, it gives the error message

```
error: invalid operands of types 'bool' and 'float' to binary 'operator>>'
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float num;  // Works when num is an 'int', but not when its a 'float'
    std::cout << "Input number:";
    std::cin >> num;
    if (!std::cin >> num){
        std::cout << "It is not float.";
    }
}
```

Comment: By the time you've read the user's input into a `float`, it's too late to do anything about it if it turns out the user wasn't intending to input a float; the bytes have already been consumed.  I'd suggest reading the user's input into a `std::string` instead, then you can inspect the contents of the string to see if it contains digits or letters, and decide how to you want to parse the string's contents based on that.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Rather than scanning the string, I'd suggest passing it to `std::stof` and catching any exception. Take advantage of the standard library's definition of what a floating-point number looks like rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @KeithThompson sounds good to me, although the OP may have some specific ideas about what should count as "float" or not (e.g. is "42" a float or an int?  I think `std::stof()` would classify it as a float but OP might want to handle it as an int)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner `std::stof()` also accepts `"INFINITY"`, `"NAN"`, and a number of variations. (I'm guessing the OP can safely ignore that.) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unary operator `!` has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `>>`, so the expression

```
!std::cin >> num
```

is parsed as

```
(!std::cin) >> num
```

which attempts to call `operator>>(bool, float)`. No such overload is defined, hence the error.

It looks like you meant to write

```
!(std::cin >> num)
```

---

Note that your code only "worked" when `num` was an `int` thanks to `!std::cin` (a `bool`) being [implicitly promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to an `int`. You were in fact calling `operator>>(int, int)`, which right-shifted the integer value of `!std::cin` to the right `num` times. This is no doubt not what you intended.